# Why supervisord does not log my PHP CLI fwrite(STDOUT, "message")?

Tags: php, command-line-interface, supervisord

I have a PHP command line application ( zconsole awswebhookrunner ) run by supervisord.

Supervisord does not log on the files `fwrite(STDOUT, "message")` but it does log `echo "message"`.

**Supervisord config**

```
[program:aws_webhook]
command=/home/(username)/bin/zconsole awswebhookrunner
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
numprocs=1
directory=/tmp
priority=999
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=100
stopwaitsecs=10
user=(username)
stdout_logfile=/home/(username)/logs/aws_webhook_runner.out.log
stderr_logfile=/home/(username)/logs/aws_webhook_runner.err.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=10MB
```

**PHP Code**

```
private function log($message, $type="info")
{
    $output=STDIN;
    switch ($type) {
        case "error":
            $output=STDERR;
            break;
        default:
            $output=STDIN;
    }
    $to_log=date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." ".$message;
    fwrite($output,$to_log.PHP_EOL) ;
    //echo $to_log.PHP_EOL;
    fflush($output);
    unset($to_log);
}
```

**Software version**

```
PHP version: 5.3.3
OS: CentOS 6.10
supervisord: 3.3.5
```

**Questions**

1. Is my `supervisord` setup correct?
2. Do I have a misunderstood the behavior of `fwrite(STDOUT|STDERR, $message);`?
3. Why `echo $message;` works if it is sent to STDOUT?

Comment: `$output=STDIN;` are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: Should be `STDOUT` and not sure in php 5.3 now but I would do `fopen('php://stdout', 'w')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Configuration wise, I think it is fine. Command-wise, it's a different question really.
2. You are trying to `STDIN` rather than `STDOUT`. `STDIN` is used for input `supervisord` does not deal with STDIN I think.
3. `echo` would print to STDOUT because it is its default behavior.